# How can a user know what is wrong with his question when a close vote is raised without comment?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question, scope

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27076249/3067485) was voted to be closed almost instantaneously without any comment. How can a user know what is wrong with his question when a close vote is raised without comment? This does not help to improve the question at all. My question was flagged as "off topic". I just read the help center it does not look like it is the case. It even does not meet point 4.

I am asking for a language functionality as it seems other people do. And I think this is valuable for other users and SE (maybe I am wrong about that, but this is the way I feel). Even editing the question does not help, because I got another close vote for the same reason. Two users answered and I gave them my vote, so if I delete this question they will lose reputation and that is not fair. It looks like this post will be closed and I do not think it will be for a good reason.

Comment: The close reason selected by that one and only vote so far is: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: It has already be done

Comment: What has been done?

Comment: describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: That's not the point, your question (last sentence especially) still reads like you're requesting a list of "modules" that do what you want. Remove that, just explain your problem (i.e. explain why the code you have isn't good enough), and remove the "what modules can do this" part from your question. Note the "Instead" in the close reason.

Comment: since your reputation is [over 250](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes "This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions..."), you can see the close reason by clicking "close" link shown to you under the question. This will open close dialog with votes cast displayed against specific close reason. FWIW you can also cast a vote (on _your_ questions, 250+ rep allows so) if you agree with the reason, or cast a vote for another reason. Or you can simply close that dialog if you think it deserves to stay open

Comment: I better do that quickly before loosing 6 reps (256)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're frustrated about the experience. The regulars on MSO are very much used to these kind of posts. We're happy to help to out where we can.

Comment: @rene Thank you for considering my point.

Comment: @Bart This is censure

Comment: @jlandercy If you have problems with people improving your questions (and yes, it was an improvement) then you'll probably not have a good time on this site. Just a friendly heads-up, having your posts edited is pretty normal and it's something you might want to consider a good thing.

Comment: @jlandercy I didn't only make my comment to show the consideration for *your* point....

Comment: To take his question but make it more general. I do agree that being downvoted and not giving a reason is weird. In my opinion you should give a reason if you downvote. It feels too much like a trolling Cartman otherwise. Comfortable sitting behind his desk, disagreeing with some part. People took time to ask a question, even it was not a good one. You often can not read from a question how much time and energy someone put into it. What's the point of downvoting if you can't even learn from your mistakes. Almost all people have blind spots and don't see all or even most of their mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

It is just one close vote. The question isn't close to being closed yet (that requires 3 community members).

Chalk it up to random downvoter/closer - possibly due to it reading like you are looking for an off site resource (but this is just a guess).

Thing is - we can't know why it got a close vote - only the close voter could tell you. We don't read minds.

Comment: Indeed you cannot, but could you tell me if my question looks like out of topic

Comment: Did I not just do that? Read it - "I am looking for a module" will, for some people, read as a resource request.

Comment: It reads like it because it is one.

Comment: Yes I asked for a module or another solution. I also proposed my version to solve it and I received another option 1 module based 1 python only based. Will you say that meet 4th criterion?

Comment: @jlandercy You only added that later, in the first revision of the question there was no proposed solution. Not everyone will notice that a post has been edited before they vote. I would suggest spending a little more time on the first revision of a question to avoid things like this. If you had included that code in the first revision and not asked for any modules chances are you wouldn't have received a close vote to begin with.

Comment: That was not the case for the second close vote

Comment: @jlandercy - so? What exactly do you expect from us here? All we can do is **guess**. We cannot give you a definitive answer, you know?

Comment: @jlandercy As I said, **"Not everyone will notice that a post has been edited before they vote"**. Someone could very well have opened it in a tab before you edited it and not noticed the little box saying there has been an edit.

Comment: I voted to close after the edit. As Matt says the close reason says "instead of" not " as well as" so I view the question as it stands as problematic.